# Stripping tags from xml while preserving contained text and parent tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, strip-tags

I'm trying to strip tags from some XML like the following:

```
<vocabularyModel>
<conceptDomain name="ActAccountType">
    <annotations>
        <documentation>
            <definition>
                <text>
                    <p>
                        <b>Description: </b>more txt here </p>
                    <p>
                        <i>Examples: </i>
                    </p>
                    <p/>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p>Patient billing accounts</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Cost center</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Cash</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </text>
            </definition>
        </documentation>
    </annotations>
</conceptDomain>
<conceptDomain name="ActAdjudicationInformationCode">
    <annotations>
        <documentation>
            <definition>
                <text>
                    <p>long text.</p>
                    <p>long text.</p>
                    <p>long text.</p>
                    <p>long text.</p>
                </text>
            </definition>
        </documentation>
    </annotations>
</conceptDomain>
<conceptDomain name="ActAdjudicationType">
    <annotations>
        <documentation>
            <definition>
                <text>
                    <p>
                        <b>Description: </b>more text.</p>
                    <p>
                        <i>Examples: </i>
                    </p>
                    <p/>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p>adjudicated with adjustments</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>adjudicated as refused</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>adjudicated as submitted</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </text>
            </definition>
        </documentation>
    </annotations>
</conceptDomain>
```

Where all child tags below text would be stripped but the desired xml and text would look like the following:

```
<vocabularyModel>
<conceptDomain name="ActAccountType">
    <annotations>
        <documentation>
            <definition>
                <text>
                   Description: more txt here 
                        Examples: 
                          Patient billing accounts
                          Cost center
                          Cash
                </text>
            </definition>
        </documentation>
    </annotations>
</conceptDomain>
<conceptDomain name="ActAdjudicationInformationCode">
    <annotations>
        <documentation>
            <definition>
                <text>
                    long text.
                    long text.
                    long text.
                    long text.
                </text>
            </definition>
        </documentation>
    </annotations>>
</conceptDomain>
<conceptDomain name="ActAdjudicationReason">
    <annotations>
        <documentation>
            <definition>
                <text>
                    long text.
                    long text.
                    long text.
                    long text.
                </text>
            </definition>
        </documentation>
    </annotations>
    <specializesDomain name="ActReason"/>
</conceptDomain>
<conceptDomain name="ActAdjudicationType">
    <annotations>
        <documentation>
            <definition>
                <text>
                        Description: more text.
                        Examples: 
                            adjudicated with adjustments
                            adjudicated as refused
                            adjudicated as submitted
                </text>
            </definition>
        </documentation>
    </annotations>
</conceptDomain>
```

I've tried the following found elsewhere here and modified:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p | b | li | ul | i">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

But this did not strip any of the elements, even when I restricted the match to just on element.    I've also tried a number of variations of the following:

```
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template name="strip-tags">
    <xsl:param name="html"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($html, '&lt;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($html, '&lt;')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                <xsl:with-param name="html" select="substring-after($html, '&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$html"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="definition">
    <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
        <xsl:with-param name="html" select="text"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Which will strip all tags if I leave out the identity transform, but other wise merely copies the content of the original XML.  Any help will be much appreciated.  -scott

Answer (score 0):

The output of the first stylesheet you show (if you add the missing `xsl:stylesheet` element is

```
<vocabularyModel>
   <conceptDomain name="ActAccountType">
      <annotations>
         <documentation>
            <definition>
               <text>Description: more txt here Examples: Patient billing accountsCost centerCash</text>
            </definition>
         </documentation>
      </annotations>
   </conceptDomain>
   <conceptDomain name="ActAdjudicationInformationCode">
      <annotations>
         <documentation>
            <definition>
               <text>long text.long text.long text.long text.</text>
            </definition>
         </documentation>
      </annotations>
   </conceptDomain>
   <conceptDomain name="ActAdjudicationType">
      <annotations>
         <documentation>
            <definition>
               <text>Description: more text.Examples: adjudicated with adjustmentsadjudicated as refusedadjudicated as submitted</text>
            </definition>
         </documentation>
      </annotations>
   </conceptDomain>
</vocabularyModel>
```

Which appears to be what you want. Perhaps your real input is in a namespace?

Comment: Baffling.  The actual root contains a few attributes and has a couple of siblings to the conceptDomain preceding it, but it otherwise is as shown.

Comment: Once I strip the xmlns designation off it works fine.  I don't know how to do this in xslt yet, but I'll look around for a solution.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @hsb declare the namespace in your stylesheet with a prefix (say `x`) then change `h="p | b | li | ul | i"` to `h="x:p | x:b | x:li | x:ul | x:i"` so it matches elements in the namespace not no-namespace.

Comment: Showing my ignorance here.  Perhaps I don't want to strip namespaces, just account somehow for the default one declared here xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif2" somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I see you anticipated my response.  Again, thanks for taking a look.